# iPhone: Click view behind transparent UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uiresponder

I have a UIScrollView that is set to have a clear background.  Part of the scrollview does have content, but part does not (so it shows other views behind it).  I would like to be able to click through the UIScrollView and to the MKMapView behind, but only for the transparent portion of the UIScrollView.

I have found some code which I am having a real hard time understanding how to get working:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (![self yourMethodThatDeterminesInterestingTouches:touches withEvent:event])
        [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event]; 
}
```

**Could someone help me wrap my mind around how to forward a touch event to a view that is behind another view?  Can I call - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event from a UIViewController?**

Comment: funny, I was just having the opposite problem. my touches were being passed on for some reason. give me a minute and I'll see if I can remember what was happening.

Comment: ok, my situation isn't really relevant. what is it you don't understand? passing the touches on to the nextresponder seems reasonable.

Comment: I guess I have no idea anything about the nextresponder.  How would I pass a touch onto this?

Comment: That's what the code you posted does.  You just have to write the method that determines whether or not it *should* be passed on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What we did was to subclass UIScrollView and implement logic that passes responsibility down to views under it, if the touch happens inside of the *transparent* area.

In our case the transparent area is defined by contentOffset of 120 on Y axis, meaning our content starts 120 points below the start of the UIScrollView, and the code looks like this:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (self.contentOffset.y < 0 && point.y < 0.0) {
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Obviously this response is well past its prime but hopefully this is helpful to anyone searching for a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, it's up to you to determine what touch events you care to forward to another responder. If you simply want to forward all touch events, just remove that `if` statement in the code you posted so the next responder will receive all the touch events.